# How can I install devtools with brew?

Tags: r

What can I do to solve this problem and install the devtools successfully?

```
➜  ~ brew install devtools 
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "devtools" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
➜  ~ git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
➜  ~ brew uninstall devtools
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/devtools
```

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: Fix your SSL error and make sure to use a formula that exists. How is this related to r? What OS are you using? What version of brew? What version of LibreSSL? What have you tried?

Comment: I am a newbie. Actually, I am not very clear about the relationship with R. I just saw it online that I need use R in this plugin.The version of my mac installation is macOS 10.13.5, the version of brew is Homebrew 1.8.6,  the version of libressl is stable 2.8.3 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only].I tried removing devtools to re-download it but it didn't help.

Comment: R is a programming language mostly related to math and statistics (see tag description). Homebrew is a software repository manager for Apple/MacOS. How did you try to remove devtools? Why did you try to do so? You have two separate problems from the output you're showing. The first being that there is no devtoos package the second being an SSL error while trying to clone the repository. What did you do to get more information about either one?

Comment: Ok, I didn’t figure out the classification before. But I downloaded dev tools just to get the dataset on GitHub, and this is the address：https://github.com/klainfo/DefectData

Comment: Those devtools are not related to homebrew but rather [part of R](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/devtools.html). It looks like you're mixing things up pretty badly. You might want to change your question and include additional information like what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much, and I will try another way.